# Big Query "Quota exceeded" SQL for Git-Hub pushEvent data-set

Tags: sql, github, google-bigquery, bigdata

I pretty new to Google BigQuery and only mildly comfortable with SQL and I was wonder if you guys could help me reformat my SQL statement maybe to reduce my usage? Because with my current set-up I encounter this error:

> Error: Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query
>   bytes scanned. For more information, see
>   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT
  LANGUAGE AS name,
  year,
  quarter,
  count
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      lang AS language,
      y AS year,
      q AS quarter,
      type,
      COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM (
      SELECT
        a.type type,
        b.lang lang,
        a.y y,
        a.q q
      FROM (
        SELECT
          type,
          YEAR(created_at) AS y,
          QUARTER(created_at) AS q,
          STRING(REGEXP_REPLACE(repo.url, r'(https:\/\/api\.github\.com\/repos\/)', '')) AS name
        FROM
          [githubarchive:year.2016] ) a
      JOIN (
        SELECT
          repo_name AS name,
          lang
        FROM (
          SELECT
            *
          FROM (
            SELECT
              *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY repo_name ORDER BY lang) AS num
            FROM (
              SELECT
                repo_name,
                FIRST_VALUE(language.name) OVER (PARTITION BY repo_name ORDER BY language.bytes DESC) AS lang
              FROM
                [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.languages]))
          WHERE
            num = 1
          ORDER BY
            repo_name)
        WHERE
          lang != 'null') b
      ON
        a.name = b.name)
    GROUP BY
      type,
      language,
      year,
      quarter
    ORDER BY
      year,
      quarter,
      count DESC)
  WHERE
    count >= 1000)
WHERE
  type = 'PushEvent'
LIMIT
  100
```

Basically I am attempting to build data-set of all the top 100 languages in terms of "pushes" on Git-Hub and the use D3 to visualize said data. I have used very little Data so far, but this one Query is currently 20gb, which should be below the limit.

As a Student I doubt I can afford to pay for the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query in question scans just 22.5GB which is about $0.11
The error is saying that you exceeded your [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free-tier) allowed bytes - which is 1TB
So you can run your query about 45 times within the month after which you need to wait next month

My recommendation to you is not to run this query each and every time  - but rather save result and use it in your experimentation / attempts, so yo are not wasting your 1TB that quickly!

Comment: Thanks for the information! I didn't know it was so cheap, I may be able to afford it after all. However, it appears that I have to pay for a minimum of 10tb of data which is a considerable amount, is that correct?

Comment: where 10TB came from? please clarify

Comment: There was some confusion on my end, I was in the wrong pricing section. The best way to pay for the transaction would be to set a maximum bytes billed correct?

Comment: if you want to control max bytes billed on query level  - yes - this will help you to keep yourself from accidental costly runs

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am quite new to this so I am not super comfortable yet, but this is very exciting technology at a very reasonable price.

Comment: Also consider installing [BigQuery Mate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh), since it will show you the cost for each query before running it.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - Thank you Elliott for recommending :o) - I wish I had more time to work on it and put in what I originally had in mind